# My transaction was rejected

Tags: bitcoind

I don't know what to do about this transaction it have been send for days now and today i got message saying "Transaction rejected by our node. Reason: Transaction was previously accepted but has been pruned from our database"

tx hash:  414514d02b33b80fefce96669680d3e8e54d656d432958211dc632260b26f239

I don't know what do to about this

Answer (score 0):

You should've used [another blockexplorer](https://www.blocktrail.com/BTC/tx/414514d02b33b80fefce96669680d3e8e54d656d432958211dc632260b26f239) instead of blockchain.info. The transaction didn't get confirmed due to low fees. I suggest trying to send it to ViaBTC transaction accelerator and see how things goes from there.

Comment: I discover i found the transaction back but it appear as uncomfirmed, what can i do to make it confirm and how can i add more fee to the transaction?

Comment: You can't add more fees at this point. use  [ViaBTC Accelerator](https://www.viabtc.com/tools/txaccelerator/) and send your TX HASH/ID there. It should get confirmed a few hours after doing so.